# How do I get SoundCloud information to website?

Tags: javascript, api

I am rebuilding a website for a podcast and they host all their information on Soundcloud. I've tried to get an API but the website says they are no longer giving those out. I have over 100 tracks I need to include on the website, with the episode title and episode description. Would I have to hard code every single track or is there a way to access Sound Cloud easier? And if I where to access the info would I need to use React to make it easier to code on the front end? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question asks two different things: how can I get Soundcloud data, and "should I use React". The latter is clearly opinion-based and there's no single, correct answer. It's unclear what you mean by "they're no longer giving those out"; the [API guide](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) says nothing about it being deprecated.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is what I am getting: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform

Comment: Hm, yes, I see that. Guess you either have to scrape, or do it manually.